# How to assign a value in document ready .fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am try to assign a value to the videoid parameter  in the URL below however when the url method is called in my C# MVC controller videoid is null

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var videoid;
      videoid = $scope.VideoId.id;
      $scope.alertVidUpload.show = false;
      $scope.$apply();
      $("#fileupload").fileupload({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/Videos/UploadVideoFile/?videoid=' + $("#videoIdVal").text(),
        autoUpload: true
```

Controller: method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadVideoFile(string videoid)
{
    var uploadedVideo = new VideoDetail();
    if (videoid != null)
    {
        uploadedVideo = _companyRepo.GetPostedVideo(Guid.Parse(videoid));
    }
```

I initially tried the following using the value from the angular scope object

```
url: '/Videos/UploadVideoFile/?videoid=' + $scope.VideoId.id
```

I am pretty sure `$scope.VideoId.id` has a value because I watched it in my browser and saw the value.

I tried creating an hidden label on my form and assign the value to the URL :

```
url: '/Videos/UploadVideoFile/?videoid=' + $("#videoIdVal").text(),
```

I can see the label value in my browser console `$("#videoIdVal").text()`, but when the controller method is hit `videoID` is empty

Can anyone help to figure out why I can’t assign the `videoId` parameter value to the url in the document ready function?

Comment: Can you post the MVC controller method accepting the argument ? The issue may not be the js. The method could be decorated incorrectly

Comment: I can see the call made to the controller with an empty string

Comment: Can you provide the html code producing that error ?

Comment: Dont mix jQuery and Angular like this...use directives!

Comment: Ok. No angular.. Why cant I pass this value from my html element to the document.ready fucntion: $("#videoIdVal").text()

Comment: @user1526912 Did you see the answer that I suggested below?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be running into a model binding issue instead of a JS issue. Try using the `[FromUri]` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.fromuriattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute on your method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadVideoFile([FromUri]string videoid)
{
  ....
```

You can also sanity check your network tab in Chrome/Firefox to make sure that the Id is in fact being populated. If it's being passed correctly, then model binding is your issue.